# Visual Studio Data Tools does not show me all columns

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, reporting-services

Does someone understand why I only getting every second column shown?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Click on your chart axis (program F,...) and look in the properties window for the Interval.  It is auto by default.  Change it to 1.

[image: chartaxis]